# what's up with this anonymous function syntax?

Tags: elixir

Just starting on my Elixir journey. Reading this in a book:

> "The & operator converts the expression that follows into a function."

ok, I think I got that...

```
iex(70)> f = &(&1 * &2)
#Function<12.80484245 in :erl_eval.expr/5>
iex(72)> f.(2,3)
6
```

ok, ampersand is a shorthand for anonymous function and it's arguments. But then, why this next call doesn't work?!

```
iex(73)> &(&1 * &2).() 
#Function<12.80484245 in :erl_eval.expr/5>
```

...and I can keep doing this seemingly forever:

```
iex(76)> &(&1 * &2).().().()
#Function<12.80484245 in :erl_eval.expr/5>
```

what is going on here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you wrap the anonymous function with parentheses, it will work:

```
iex(1)> (&(&1 * &2)).()
** (BadArityError) &:erlang.*/2 with arity 2 called with no arguments
```

The Error is expected, as we're calling a 2 arity fun with zero arguments. If we pass it two numbers, we should get see them get multiplied together:

```
iex(2)> (&(&1 * &2)).(2,3)
6
```

Comment: To clarify, this is not a bug and your solution is correct! The dot has higher precedence than the & on purpose, so you can write stuff like: Enum.map(users, & &1.name)

Comment: Ah, so op's expression is equivalent to &((&1 * &2).()) ?

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent!

Comment: Thanks for the answer - but could you (either of) elaborate on why this is happening? I'm not sure if I understand the deal with the precedence - repeated stacking of '.()' doesn't change anything - the same 0-argument function is returned..

Comment: @alexakarpov as Jose explained, dot (.) has higher precedence. This means that dots are applied before & is even considered, so & turns everything into a lambda. So your repeated stacking just amounts to &((&1*&2).().().()) that returns a function. Think of it as analogue to IO.puts 3*3*3 - multiplications are applied before IO.puts is applied. Bottom line: if unsure - use parens :-)

Comment: Another little clarification to what @sasajuric has written: the "&((&1*&2).().().())" returns function of two arguments, so it's a correct expression but the function will fail when called, because (&1*&2) does not return function and therefore can't be called (by succeeding ".()"):
iex(1)> (&(&1 * &2).().().()).(3,3)  
** (BadFunctionError) expected a function, got: 9

Comment: Too bad the compiler doesn't pick this up... shouldn't it know the result of * won't be a function? Or is this something you'd use dialyzer for?